# Adding Sample(TimeSpan span) to Reactive Extensions pipeline causes threading issues

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Using Reactive Extensions, I have created a rolling buffer of values that caches a small history of recent values in a data stream for use in a plotting application.  Since the values arrive much faster than I am interested in displaying, I would like to use the Sample(Timespan span) method in my Reactive pipeline to slow things down. However, adding it to the sample below causes an Exception to be thrown after a bit in the WriteEnumerable method (collection was modified).  This is obviously a threading issue related to Sample, but I'm stumped on how exactly to alleviate it.  I've tried setting the Scheduler to use in the Sample method to no avail.

Any advice?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
            .Take(500)
            .TimedRollingBuffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
            .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
            .Subscribe(frame => WriteEnumerable(frame));

        var input = "";
        while (input != "exit")
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void WriteEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        foreach (T thing in enumerable)
            Console.WriteLine(thing + " " + DateTime.UtcNow);

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IObservable<IEnumerable<Timestamped<T>>> TimedRollingBuffer<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, TimeSpan timeRange)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<Timestamped<T>>>(
            o =>
            {
                var queue = new Queue<Timestamped<T>>();
                return observable.Timestamp().Subscribe(
                    tx =>
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(tx);
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        while (queue.Peek().Timestamp < now.Subtract(timeRange))
                            queue.Dequeue();

                        o.OnNext(queue);
                    },
                    ex => o.OnError(ex),
                    () => o.OnCompleted()
                    );
            });
    }
}
```

credit where credit is due: [reactive extensions sliding time window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559255/reactive-extensions-sliding-time-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is due to the fact you are modifying the queue whilst enumerating it.

The [`RollingBuffer` implementation you cited by @Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559255/reactive-extensions-sliding-time-window) does the right thing - you will notice in his implemention the `OnNext` is invoked with a `ToArray()` ensuring a copy of the list as it stands is dispatched to observers rather than the mutating original.

In your case, the introduction of `Sample` introduces concurrency (which is fine - that's what it is supposed to do) - however, you are passing the queue itself, which will mutate whilst enumeration is occurring due to this introduced concurrency. This is a bug.

In your `TimedRollingBuffer`, if you were to use `o.OnNext(queue.ToArray())` instead of `o.OnNext(queue)` you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Mutability strikes again!

Comment: yeah, I'm still getting myself into the properly functional mindset - mutability has bitten me a couple times.....